# Is the "load data infile" command in MySQL unsafe in general, or just when using statement based replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm also trying to understand why MySQL considers "load data infile" unsafe and switches to RBR if running in mixed mode, does that mean it is only unsafe when using SBR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, [there is a trace](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34283) on why they marked it unsafe in 5.5.6 and also in 5.1.52

> There are several problems with reproducing LOAD DATA INFILE queries in this manner:
>
> - If the user does not know the internal workings of mysqlbinlog, the temp files will
>   accumulate on disk and never be removed.
> - There is no easy way to remove the temp files automatically (the safest way is to
>   parse the output of mysqlbinlog, which is hard and there is still no guarantee that the
>   format never changes, etc.)
> - Temp files will accumulate on the pushbuild server.

Comment: Your answer is a much more compact version of my novel. +1 !!!

Comment: Do you mean that if I'm using SBR that there are temp files for me to clean up, but with RBR there are not?

Comment: Correct. RBR stores the rows that were changed ONLY in the binlog. no need for a temp file.