# Insert Missing Data in Slave Database

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication

We have a master slave replication [MySQL 5.6]. However In slave database 2 rows is missing in one table. I've tried to solve this using Percona Toolkit as suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14224/71925).

> But `pt-table-checksum` requires statement-based replication, and it sets `binlog_format=STATEMENT` on the master, but due to a MySQL limitation replicas do not honor this change. Therefore, checksums will not replicate past any replicas using row-based replication that are masters for further replicas.

***So what if:***

1. **Insert the rows directly into the slave database**

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;

INSERT INTO `tbl_name` (`id`, `column1`, ...)
VALUES ( 4321, 'some val', ...),
       ( 4344, 'some val2', ...);
```

2. **Run a `REPLACE INTO` query in Master database**

```
REPLACE INTO `tbl_name` (`id`, `column1`, ...)
VALUES ( 4321, 'some val', ...);

REPLACE INTO `tbl_name` (`id`, `column1`, ...)
VALUES ( 4344, 'some val2', ...);
```

Can someone suggest which method is safe and reliable. Is this the right way to solve the issue. Is there any risk of doing this?

Comment: "will not replicate past..." -- Please show us your entire topology and explain which servers need which fixes.

Comment: `REPLACE` = `DELETE` based on _all_ unique keys, followed by one `INSERT`.

Comment: Are the binlogs turned on on the Slave(s)?

Comment: Seems like #1 is sufficient and safe.  Seems like #2 is redundant (but possibly easier for the toolkit to perform).

Comment: @RickJames thanks. #1 will be run on slave database and #2 will be run on master database. Is is good to run insert query in slave database? By conversion it should be on read only mode.