# Loading data in mysql using LOAD DATA INFILE, replication safe?

Tags: mysql, replication, import, csv

I am trying to load data into mysql database form CSV file. I found that we could use LOAD DATA INFILE command to do it. But as per the mysql documentation it is not replication safe. (See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-load-data.html))

Is there a better way to do it rather than to do it via application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are absolutely right**. it is not replication-safe. In fact, I wrote about how LOAD DATA INFILE replicates back on Jan 22, 2012 : [MySql shell command not replicated to slave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10723/mysql-shell-command-not-replicated-to-slave/11256#11256). Basically, the entire data file is stored in the binary logs, replicated to the Slave, manifested as a text file in /tmp, and the LOAD DATA INFILE is executed.

What could help is setting sync-binlog=1 before running LOAD DATA INFILE. Notwithstanding, Replication of a large CSV file is at the mercy of replication and the network.

## SUGGESTION

For a Text File called `mydata.csv`, you are better off doing the following:

Step 01 : `cp mydata.csv to mydata.csv2`

Step 02 : Make the script LoadMaster.sql

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
SET bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mydata.csv' INTO tb1 ... ;
```

Step 03 : Make the script LoadSlave.sql

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
SET bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mydata.csv2' INTO tb1 ... ;
```

Step 04: Load both in parallel

```
mysql -hIPMaster -u... -p... < LoadMaster.sql &
mysql -hIPSlave  -u... -p... < LoadSlave.sql &
wait
```

If you have multiple slaves, you could do this:

```
mysql -hIPMaster -u... -p... < LoadMaster.sql &
mysql -hIPSlave1  -u... -p... < LoadSlave.sql &
mysql -hIPSlave2  -u... -p... < LoadSlave.sql &
mysql -hIPSlave3  -u... -p... < LoadSlave.sql &
....
wait
```

That way

- both imports are done together
- binlogs are not bloated
- CSV file can always be deleted

Comment: Thanks @Rolando, this is very helpful, do I have to do it for each slaves if it has multiple?

Comment: I am afraid so it you want each Slave loaded without replication. You could do it serial fashion as well if network traffic is a concern.

Comment: all the slaves are internal, so i am not concerned about the network traffic.. I just want to make sure the data is replicated in all the instances.

Comment: i am a newbie on this.. so when u run the commands in step 4, the sql that gets run in master.. doesn't it try to run it in slave automatically by replication? how do we ensure the sql is only run in master and is not replication as we run it paralleled?

Comment: That's why The first line of each SQL script is `SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;`. That prevents an SQL statement from being recorded in the binary logs. If a Master does not record an SQL statement, then it does not get replicated.

Comment: sounds good.. just curious as to why we had to make a copy of the CSV file? couldn't they both use the same? because in the multiple slaves, we will be invoking same sql? also both master and slave sql looks exactly the same .. could same file be used? or should each of the slave has its own copy of CSV and SQL files?

Comment: I worry about file handle contention on the same file. You can try on the same file if you wish.

Comment: another point, the table i am trying to insert to say is 
DATA1(id, name, phone). the csv file only has (name, phone), so in my db i have id as auto increment field. I import name and phone. So with this approach, will be there be any issue? the ID field is useless at this time. it does not get used by application or anything.

Comment: USe dummy column to bypass ID column you don't need. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139069/how-to-skip-columns-in-csv-file-when-importing-into-mysql-table-using-load-data

Answer (score 5):

Another answer has already been accepted, but **I disagree with that answer**, because your question first requires an understanding of the meaning of the term "unsafe" and the phrase "considered unsafe" when it is used related to MySQL replication.

> When speaking of the “safeness” of a statement in MySQL Replication, we are referring to whether a statement and its effects can be replicated correctly **using statement-based format.**
>   <sub>http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html (emphasis added)</sub>

There is no such thing as an "unsafe" statement when you are using `MIXED` or `ROW`-based replication, because the entire premise of "unsafe" is related to how statement-based logging and replication work.

Something "considered unsafe" doesn't mean it shouldn't be done -- it means *the optimizer will consider it unsafe to log in statement-based mode* and therefore that it will be automatically replicated using the row-based replication logging format if row-based logging is available -- that is, if you are not using `binlog_format` = `STATEMENT` -- which you should not be doing unless you have a specific reason to use it.  If you are not aware of a specific reason to use it, then you most likely do not have one, and you should used `MIXED` logging, so that the optimizer can choose how to replicate each statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-formats.html

Comment: I agree with your statement about 'unsafe'. But curious from a performance standpoint, which is better for a large-ish `LOAD DATA INFILE` command: replicating via row-based, or parallel `LOAD DATA` commands run on each server as in @Rolando's answer?

Comment: I haven't benchmarked the other method.  I rarely use `LOAD DATA INFILE`, since I often deal in files that aren't plain text, and at any rate I prefer to have an external application parse the file and do primitive structural validation.  In some cases, my "loader" applications are designed with the ability to monitor `Seconds_Behind_Master` on the slaves while they are running, and will actually throttle themselves to write less aggressively to the master if or when a replication lag occurs.