# how to set bulk_insert_buffer_size in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, myisam

I want to set bulk_insert_buffer_size variable for insert. I searched from other pages too, all they are saying about my.cnf. But there is no my.cnf in my system. I checked my.ini and there is no such variable there.

I also tried through command line -

```
SET GLOBAL bulk_insert_buffer_size= 268435456;
```

It shows -

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: SET GLOBAL bulk_insert_buffer_size =1024*1024*256

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.001 sec
Total Time     : 0.002 sec
```

but on running -

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%bulk%';
```

I am getting the same(old one) -

```
Variable_name            Value    
bulk_insert_buffer_size  8388608
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. 
I am using Mysql 5.5 version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you ran

```
SET GLOBAL bulk_insert_buffer_size =1024*1024*256;
```

what you did was set the insert buffer to 256M for *incoming DB Connections going forward*.

To set it for your current DB session, run this in that session:

```
SET bulk_insert_buffer_size =1024*1024*256;
```

Then, you can run

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%bulk%';
```

and see a different value.

In a [**post made back on April 18, 2013 (see Steps 2 and 3)**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40400/loading-data-in-mysql-using-load-data-infile-replication-safe/40402#40402), I suggested setting the bulk_insert_buffer_size to 256M within a current session.

If you want to keep that value when you restart mysql, just add this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 256M
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: these are for the myisam tables only not for innodb if i am not wrong here

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam you are correct. Please note that the question has a `myisam` tag.